# How to extract the text without HTML tags out of a webpage using HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm just getting started with HTMLUnit and what I'm looking to do is take a webpage and extract out the raw text from it minus all the html markup.

Can htmlunit accomplish that? If so, how? Or is there another library I should be looking at?

for example if the page contains

```
<body><p>para1 test info</p><div><p>more stuff here</p></div>
```

I'd like it to output

```
para1 test info more stuff here
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html indicates that this is indeed possible.

```
@Test
public void homePage() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
    assertEquals("HtmlUnit - Welcome to HtmlUnit", page.getTitleText());

    final String pageAsXml = page.asXml();
    assertTrue(pageAsXml.contains("<body class=\"composite\">"));

    final String pageAsText = page.asText();
    assertTrue(pageAsText.contains("Support for the HTTP and HTTPS protocols"));
}
```

**NB:** the page.asText() command seems to offer exactly what you are after.

[Javadoc for asText](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#asText%28%29) (Inherited from DomNode to HtmlPage)

Comment: anyway to do this with the htmlclient library?

Comment: Looks like it is possible (I assume you are referring to Apache HttpClient) - http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/TrivialApp.java?view=markup